# Why does activeresource.rb just call active_resource.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

Here are the entire contents of `activeresource.rb`:

```
require 'active_resource'
```

Could someone explain the logic of this?

Why not simply have `activeresource.rb` contain what `active_resource.rb` contains and forget about the additional `require` statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[David Heinemeier Hansson](http://www.loudthinking.com/) added activeresource.rb to the code base so that people can do their requires based on the gem name itself and not have to remember that even though the gem is named activeresource they have to require active_resource.rb

The original file was still needed for anyone who was already using it, so the new file just requires the old.

[Check In Comment For activeresource.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master/activeresource/lib/activeresource.rb)

Edit:

Found the original [enhancement ticket](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/8845) that resulted in this change